# Comparing values in dictionaries python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 2 nested dictionaries in Python that have this format:

```
1166869: {'probL2': '0.000', 'probL1': '0.000', 'pronNDiff_site': '1.000', 'StateBin': '0', 'chr': 'chrX', 'rangehist': '59254000-59255000', 'start_bin': '59254000', 'countL2': '4', 'countL1': '0'} 

1166870: {'probL2': '0.148', 'probL1': '0.000', 'pronNDiff_site': '0.851', 'StateBin': '0', 'chr': 'chr2', 'rangehist': '59254000-59255000', 'start_bin': '59255000', 'countL2': '5', 'countL1': '15'} 

1166871: {'probL2': '0.000', 'probL1': '0.000', 'pronNDiff_site': '1.000', 'StateBin': '0', 'chr': 'chrY', 'rangehist': '59290000-59291000', 'start_bin': '59290000', 'countL2': '1', 'countL1': '2'}
```

where 1166869, 1166870 and 1166871 represent a line in a file from where I read the data, and the rest of the keys are the data itself.

Now I want to make a list where I store all the different values in the key "chr" because there are some repeated ones.

How can I go through the dictionary and make the comparison between the 2 values? This code is not working:

```
for k in range(len(file_dict)):
    for j in range(len(file_dict)-1):
        if (file_dict[j]["chr"] != file_dict[k]["chr"]):
            list_chr.append(file_dict[j]["chr"])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a set, and just all the items in one go:

```
chr = { v['chr'] for v in file_dict.itervalues() }
```

This uses a set comprehension to generate your set in one line of code.

Set comprehensions were introduced in Python 2.7; in earlier versions use:

```
chr = set(v['chr'] for v in file_dict.itervalues())
```

In Python 3, you'd need to replace `.itervalues()` by `.values()`.

Your own code doesn't work because python dictionaries are not lists; you don't retrieve values by index, but by key. You'd have to change it to:

```
for key in file_dict:
    for other_key in file_dict:
        if key == other_key:
            continue

        if file_dict[key]['chr'] != file_dict[otherkey]['chr']:
            list_chr.append(filed_dict[key]['chr'])
```

but that is *really* inefficient, not to mention incorrect.

Comment: I cannot run the code chr = { v['chr'] for v in file_dict.itervalues() }, it says invalid syntax.

Comment: @Leo.peis: The syntax was introduced in Python 2.7, I'll update.

Comment: You might replace `itervalues` by `values` in python3.

Comment: @Leo.peis: I tested the code in Python 2.7. Did you copy the code correctly? Check the line *before* this one to see if you perhaps forgot to close a parenthesis or something.

Comment: should I delete my own respinse as it is a a duplication of yours?

Comment: @azorius: not if you don't want to. If you feel your answer adds something that is missing from mine for example. You are perfectly entitled to answer this question too.

Comment: appart from telling that a list is O(n) and a set is O(1) it is pretty much the same as your answer just 15 minuts delayed

Answer (score 1):

how about something along the lines of:

```
list_chr = list(set([val['chr'] for val in file_dict.values()]))
```

how does this work?

first a list comprehension gets all the chr entries in the inner dict
these are then converted to a set, such that there are no duplicate entries
these are then converted to a list if that's the format you prefere

please note that maybe you really want to use a set, then the look up time is O(1) instead of O(n)